# Easier way to convert file dependency to textbox text in method?

Tags: c#, wpf

A colleague of mine supplied a .dll file with certain functions inside. I am trying to incorperate this .dll into an app I'm making.

For now, it looks like this (code shortened for improved readiblity) :

```
    public static void ExecuteProject(string project)
    {
        string projectPath = @"" + project + ".txt";
        LConvertRows(File.ReadAllText(projectPath), Model, Statements);

    }
```

For now it is dependend on a file inside of the debug folder.
I am trying to replace projectpath with text inside of a textbox. Like so :

```
        View T = new View();
        string projectPath = T.txt_CodeDetail.Text;
```

EDIT : This is the button that summons the method, and supplies the project string

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ExecuteProject();

    }
```

Since the depend file is a .txt file I didnt think this would be a problem.
This however, shows the following error :

```
        System.IO.PathTooLongException: 'The specified path, file name, or both are too long. 
        The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, 
        and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.
```

I've read this doesn't happen at .NET Framework 4.6.2, I am however stuck with 4.5.2 due to external conditions.
I've also read about a library `Delimon.Win32.IO.dll` that fixes this issue, but can not find a link to it anywhere.

Comment: You could also try [AlphaFS](https://github.com/alphaleonis/AlphaFS) library which I've used in the past which gets around this issue by using the native calls that can deal with long paths. But you should also be able to set the appropriate [registry key](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/learn-explore/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/The-Windows-10-default-path-length-limitation-MAX-PATH-is-256-characters.html) to enable long path support depending on your version of Windows. Then you access paths with long path syntax `\\?\c:\longpathhere`

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 I'm getting a different error now that could be due to my programming. With AlphaFS installed projectpath is picking up only the code that was initially in the textbox when opening up the application (I think due to the new instance?) So were I to copy my text inside I get an "Path is a zero-length string or contains only white spaces" exception despite copying characters inside. How can I fix this?

Comment: There's also [Pri.LongPath](https://github.com/peteraritchie/LongPath) which provides long-path-safe versions of the `File`/`Directory`/`Path` APIs

Comment: @Tymaca I do no understand a single thing you said. You installed AlphaFS, but did you switch to the methods in their library? You can't just keep calling `System.IO.File.ReadAllTex`t, you need to explicitly call the version in their library--which is named the same thing... Just different namespace: `Alphaleonis.Win32.Filesystem.File.ReadAllText`

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 I did. That changed my problem. When the application is booted up the textbox that I want to replace the file with is blank, the user can copy and paste their text inside of it to run it through the method. Using AlphaFS, instead of the earlier System.IO.PathTooLong error. I now get an error that T.txt_CodeDetail.txt is empty, despite pasting characters in there. I'm relatively sure this is due to the way I programmed, but have no idea where to look